Javascript working on Cargo staging site, but not on published site
The following JS for an accordion drop-down is working fine on my staging site (using Cargo), but try as I might - it won't drop-down on the live site!
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}</script>

